# Как убрать границы у select, чтобы это было кроссбраузерно?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть список `select` который лежит на белом фоне и нужно у него убрать границы. Если задаю `border: none;`, то в хроме все хорошо, а в мозилле, опере и едже появляется у стрелки серый бекграунд с границей - как от него избавиться?

```css
div {
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 3;
}
select {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="Выбор">Выбор</option>
    <option value="1-ая">1-ая</option>
    <option value="2-ая">2-ая</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Имхо, только нарисовать свой дроплист или использовать готовое решение (например от bootstrap)

Comment: @tutankhamun а можно подробнее, про готовое решение от `bootstrap`? мне бы просто фон серый убрать

Comment: Я имел ввиду нечто подобное: http://www.bootply.com/b4NKREUPkN Останется стилизовать тему бутстрапа или выборочно переопределить стили

Comment: @tutankhamun аа, я понял - имеете ввиду `select` заменить на `ul` нее, это способ мне в данном случае не подойдет, т.к. селект - это элемент плагина отправки формы на `wordpress`

Comment: Немного js и hidden-поле решит проблему, но это дело личное. Я давно забросил попытки хорошо и кроссбраузерно стилизовать select-поля. Либо оставляю "как есть", либо подменяю на кастомные дроплисты.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо убрать стандартный `appearance` и (желательно) `user-select`.

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
-ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;

-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: radio-container;
 appearance: none;
```

Comment: как убрать - вот так? 
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27625/
что-то пока не очень понимаю. мне бы просто фон убрать

Comment: Интересное решение. Только из CSS3 это свойство уже [убрали](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance#See_also), а ИЕ даже не успели выпустить глюк к нему

Comment: @Вася, при помощи этих свойств вы убираете стандартное оформление, а дальше стилизуйте этот селект так, как вам будет нужно.

Comment: @tutankhamun вопрос был про конкретные браузеры — мозиллу, оперу и эдж, там этим свойством можно оперировать, несмотря на спецификацию. http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Не подумайте, что я оспариваю ваше решение, просто указал для информации. Убрали из спецификации, значит могут и поменять поведение параметра. Это нужно будет учитывать. А сам ответ я даже плюсанул.